# Instantiate Spring bean with InputStream constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, inputstream

I am trying to instantiate a Spring bean in the following way:

```
<bean id="myParser class="com.parser.MyParser">
    <constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream"
        value="classpath:regex.yaml" />
</bean>
```

MyParser has the following constructors defined:

```
 public MyParser() throws IOException {
    this(MyParser.class.getResourceAsStream(DEFAULT_YAML_PATH));
  }

  public MyParser(InputStream regexYaml) {
    initialize(regexYaml);
  }
```

But on runtime I receive an error that the bean cannot be created because a matching constructor could not be found:

```
Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Comment: Do you have control over `MyParser`?

Comment: No, it's an external jar file.

Answer (score -1):

Found the error, apparently if the file is not on the classpath then the InputStream can not be instantiated and it will result in the error above.